# Collocate with adjectives

Tags: adjectives, adverbs, collocation

Recently I have learnt stronger adverbs( absolutely, completely, totally) never collocate with non-extreme adjectives. So how do we know whether we can use "stronger adverbs" with a adj or not? Should we learn all the non-extreme adjectives?

Comment: The term is _polar_, not _stronger_. These can only apply to adjectives that lie on the end of a scale (its "pole"), like _boiling_ or _freezing_. You can say _absolutely boiling_ or _absolutely freezing_ but not *_absolutely cool_, for instance. When  you learn adjectives, you need to learn what scales they appear on, and where they lie. It makes it much easier to know when to use which one.

Comment: John Lawler thank you very much, it is really helpful. Is there any web sources that help to know what scale an adj lie on? Thanks for advanced!